# VBA Join equivalent for Collections

Tags: vba, join, collections, excel

How do I join a collection in VBA. In VB.net I usually join arrays using Join(..., "delimiter), but I cant figure out how to do this using collection in VBA.

```
Dim oColl As New Collection
Dim r As Range

Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Work1").Range("D13:D263")

For Each cell In r
     If IsEmpty(cell) Then

     Else
         oColl.Add ("a = ''" + cell.Text + "'' ")
     End If
Next
```

I need to now join all the collection values into one string

Comment: Can you post a sample of your collection?

Comment: I added the example collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own question, I simply declared a string placeholder and in a for each for items in the collection I added to the string then output the results of the single string placeholder.

Answer (score 5):

While you have solved your question you could speed up your code by

1. Using `SpecialCells` to work with the non-blanks rather than test each cell
2. Use a variant array rather than a range loop

The code below uses `Join` to merge the final strings together. If you didn't have the string manipulation (the `"a = ''" + cell.Text + "'' "` part) then you could simply join the specialcells range from step 1

**Updated to handle multiple areas in the SpecialCells Collection and single cells (where varinats wont work"**

```
Sub Diff()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim varTest
Dim strOut As String
Dim lngrow As Long
On Error Resume Next
With Range("D13:D263")
    Set rng1 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng1 = Union(rng1, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas))
    Else
        Set rng1 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    End If
End With
On Error GoTo 0
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
    If rng2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        varTest = Application.Transpose(rng2)
        For lngrow = 1 To UBound(varTest)
            varTest(lngrow) = "a = ''" & varTest(lngrow) & "'' "
        Next
        strOut = strOut & Join(varTest, ",")
    Else
        strOut = strOut & "a = ''" & rng2.Value & "'' "
    End If
Next
MsgBox strOut
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the use of special cells, but I don't think the code will always work, you can't application.Transpose a non continuous array if there are blanks then rng1 will be non continuous.

Comment: @kyle good pick-up. I have updated for this and the potential single cell issue. btw did you actually upvote this given it is still at 1? :)

Comment: Hmmm, thought I had, definitely have now though :)

Comment: This looks really complicated but I guess it could work, I cbf changing my code though and I really wanted to use the collection so I might just stick to using collections. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I reckon mine below is the most simple, I'm too simple to come up with complex ways of doing things ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
joinedString = "a='" & Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(Sheet1.Range("D13:D263").Value), "',a='"), ",a=''", "")
```

Comment: +1 cleverly done rendering my effort overkill. Perhaps trim the extra value at the end. kudos